# create a file list of a folder using c #

Tags: c#, directory, directoryinfo, filelist

How can i create a list of file in a folder and save it in a txt file, using c#?
I tried to start but but I stopped because I do not know how to go on!

Thank you

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(folderOutput.SelectedPath);
```

Comment: Start looking at the docs for your [DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Then look at the docs of the [File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: Do you have troubles getting the directory listing or saving it to a file?

Comment: `var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderOutput.SelectedPath);` to get all files; `File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\MyFile.txt", files);` to save them

Answer (score 0):

```
*DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(#DirectoryLocation);
```

List Lists = new List();
Lists.AddRange(di.GetFiles());*

will make List of files.

after that, as Dmitry Bychenko said, you can write lists to txt file.